# How to export an IFC file of a high-rise based on each storey

Tags: model, revit, ifc

I have a 3D model of a highrise with 100 levels in Revit. I would like to separate this file based on each storey. I mean, I would like to have 100 Revit files (or IFC files) for each level from this 3D model. What is the best solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution would presumably be to leave the model intact, create 100 views, one for each floor, and set up the section box in each one of them to correspond to a different floor, cf. the official Revit help documentation section [Export Part of a 3D View](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-DAD0D8BD-C17B-4FCB-9635-C53925A47AA6-htm.html).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  Your answer is really helpful. Now I would like to export the building block (all exterior face e.g. exterior walls, roofs,...), how I can specify it for the export? Is there any easy approach for doing this?

Comment: As mostly with Revit, there are probably numerous possible approaches. As always, you should first determine the optimal workflow and best practices using the manual end user interface before considering how to solve it programmatically. The first thing that comes to mind when you say "exterior faces" is to make use of the gbXML export and [Building Performance Analysis](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/11/building-performance-analysis-and-face-tessellation.html#2).

Comment: Cf. the [energy analysis API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/07/self-organising-architecture-and-voxel-based-energy-analysis.html#6) and [Energy Model Types](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/family-category-and-two-energy-model-types.html#3).

Comment: Thank you again Jeremy for your reply. Could you please make that more clear. You mean when I export the model to gbXML, it simplifies the model and remove internal geometries? As I have Revit LT, it does not support gbXML export. So I cannot test this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will investigate that further.